# How to retrieve parameters sent with http.get

Tags: php, angularjs, web-services, http

I am using http.get to get data from database. I am sending the parameters along with url. but the parameters are not accessible from that url.

Here is my Angularjs controller code :

```
app.controller('ListCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$location', '$window', function($scope,$http,$location,$window){
$scope.data = {};
$scope.getdata = function(){
    $scope.datas = [];
    $http({
        url: "http://localhost/angular/data.php", 
        method: "GET",
        params: {'place':$scope.data.place,'pincode':$scope.data.pincode}
    })
    .success(function(data,status,headers,config){
        $scope.datas=data;
        console.log($scope.datas);
        $scope.navig('/show.html');
    })
    .error(function(){
         alert("failed");
    });
};
$scope.navig = function(url){
    $window.location.href = url;
};
}])
```

And here is my **data.php** file

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");

$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
$data= json_decode($postdata);
$place = mysql_real_escape_string($data->place);
$pincode = mysql_real_escape_string($data->pincode);

//$place = $_GET[$data->place];

if ($place){

    $connection = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","building") or die("Error " . mysqli_error($connection));
    $sql = "SELECT * from details ";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql) or die("Error in Selecting " . mysqli_error($connection));

    $detail = array();

    while($row =mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        $detail[] = $row;
    }

    echo json_encode($detail);
    mysqli_close($connection);
}
else {
    echo "no place entered";
}
?>
```

It outputs as "no place entered" even if I enter the place.

Is that the right way to retrieve the data?

I am passing either place or pincode, not both. will that cause any issue?

please help.

Comment: You are using GET in your AJAX call but expecting POST in your PHP by `file_get_contents("php://input")`. Choose one of them.

Comment: I am a newbie and I don't know exactly how to get that parameters. what should I use instead of file_get_contents("php://input") . I have to use GET  not POST.

Comment: To access GET parameters, use $_GET global array and not php://input which is the input from the request body.

Comment: @RonDadon. thanks . using $_GET easily solved it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it. Here is the solution.

I used these two line of code

```
$place = $_GET['place'];
$pincode= $_GET['pincode'];
```

instead of these 4 lines of code which is actually used to retrieve data sent with **http.post**

```
$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
$data= json_decode($postdata);
$place = mysql_real_escape_string($data->place);
$pincode = mysql_real_escape_string($data->pincode);
```